# GridView children sometimes not drawing

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a GridView with a custom view which basically look like buttons. The gridview starts off with no children, and everytime the user presses a button another custom view will be added.

There is some strange behaviour with this. I am drawing some things like text, lines etc on the custom view in onDraw and sometimes they are drawn at all. They are completely blank. The behaviour seems quite random in terms of which views show or don't show the drawn graphics.

I have a feeling it is to do with me setting the layoutparameters. I store the child views in an array once they are created, and in getView() I return the view relevant for the position parameter. So I only ever create buttons for each position once.

So I have two questions.

1. What am I doing to cause this?
2. Should I even be using a gridview for what I am doing?

The code for get view is:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        GridButton button;
        GridView gridView = (GridView)parent;
        if(childBuittons.size() <= position) //if we need to create a new button
        {
                button = createButton(position);
                int nWidth = getButtonSize(gridView);
                GridView.LayoutParams params = new GridView.LayoutParams(nWidth, nWidth);
                button.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
        else //we already have a button that we created
        {
            button = buttons.get(position);
        }
        return button;
    }
```

Some more information:
- The gridbutton class is just a class that extends View and overrides onDraw to draw some graphics such as text and lines
- What im trying to achieve is a grid of squares that the user can add or remove (although they wont do this often) and then press the squares to perform certain functions
- It is possible that there will be more squares than can fit in the screen

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing to cause this?

Without providing more details related to the GridButton class nobody can really help you. It would be good to know how you handle the measuring of the view and what(and how) exactly do you draw in that view.

> I have a feeling it is to do with me setting the layoutparameters.

I doubt this. To be sure you could also draw a simple color in that custom view and see if it appears on the grid. If it does the `LayoutParams` aren't the reason for what's happening. Also check what values do you get for `nWidth`.

> I store the child views in an array once they are created, and in
>   getView() I return the view relevant for the position parameter. So I
>   only ever create buttons for each position once.

This is not ok. The main reason for using a `GridView` is that you could use its adapter to avoid having to create all grid views(occupying memory(if not crashing) and slowing your app) up front. You should look in implementing the proper recycling mechanism specific to a `GridView`/`ListView`. Your `getView()` method should be like this:

```
View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    GridButton button;
    GridView gridView = (GridView)parent;
    if(convertView == null) {
            button = createButton(position);
            int nWidth = getButtonSize(gridView);
            GridView.LayoutParams params = new GridView.LayoutParams(nWidth, nWidth);
            button.setLayoutParams(params);
    } else {
        button = (GridButton) convertView;
    }
    return button;
}
```

If you need access to those buttons then access them through the adapter, changing some data according to the button's position and calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

> Should I even be using a gridview for what I am doing?

You didn't say what you want do do. If you think that the number of cells is high enough and it's expected to not see all of them then use a `GridView`. If you think all the cells will be visible then you could make that grid using the standard layouts without a `GridView`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated my question to hopefully provide some more information. I understand the whole recycling thing (or maybe I dont) - I just thought it would be more efficient to return a View already created and stored and set up which is held in an array rather than re-initialise it every time

Comment: @gcb The `GridView`'s recycling mechanism is more than enough(and the recommended way of handling things). if you didn't solved the issue yet, maybe you could post the `onDraw method of your custom view.

Comment: Actually I decided to try out a gridlayout instead, and it makes much more sense for what I was trying to do and works perfectly.